# Is the set $\{P\in \mathcal{P}:\mathbf{E}_P[\xi]\leq 0,\mathbf{E}_P[\xi^2]\leq 1\}$ closed?

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose $\xi$ a random variable defined on $\mathbb{R}$ with sigma-algebra $\mathcal{F}$. Let $\mathcal{P}$ denote the set of all probability measures on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{F})$.  Is $\{P\in \mathcal{P}:\mathbf{E}_P[\xi]\leq 0,\mathbf{E}_P[\xi^2]\leq 1\}$  closed ?     You can assume weak convergence

Comment: What's the topology on $\mathcal P$?

Comment: Weak convergence or total variation